# Python converting string into json object

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Output is

```
"Passanger status:\n passanger cfg086d96 is unknown\n\n"
```

i want to convert this into json object like

```
{
  "Passanger_status": "passanger cfg086d96 is unknown"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just apply `json.dumps()` to this native python dictionary composed in one-line:

```
{k.replace(" ","_"):v.strip() for k,v in (x.split(":") for x in ["Passanger status:\n passanger cfg086d96 is unknown\n\n"])}
```

the inner generator comprehension avoids to call `split` for each part of the dict key/value. The value is stripped to remove trailing/leading blank spaces. The space characters in the key are replaced by underscores.

result is (as dict):

```
{'Passanger status': 'passanger cfg086d96 is unknown'}
```

as json string using `indent` to generate newlines:

```
>>> print(json.dumps({k.replace(" ","_"):v.strip() for k,v in (x.split(":") for x in ["Passanger status:\n passanger cfg086d96 is unknown\n\n"])},indent=2))
{
  "Passanger_status": "passanger cfg086d96 is unknown"
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make "Passanger status"  as "Passanger_status"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one also

```
data_dic = dict()
data = "Passanger status:\n passanger cfg086d96 is unknown\n\n"
x1 , x2 = map(str,data.split(":"))
data_dic[x1] = x2
print data_dic
```

If you find it simple

Output :

```
{'Passanger status': '\n passanger cfg086d96 is unknown\n\n'}
```

and for space to underscore  you can use replace method in keys of the dictionary.